# Trailing Zeron in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add a trailing zero to the `126.0` value in my `nodes near coords`.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

When I add the line `nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1},` it adds the trailing zero, BUT also reworks my `0.2` so it looks like `$2 \cdot 10^(-1)$`:

[image]

How can I display `126.0` and `0.2`just like that at the same time?

Thank you in advance!

The full code:

```
\documentclass[
    conference,
    ]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\twh{\tera\watt\hour}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={Stromerzeugung in \SI{}{\twh}},
    symbolic x coords={
        Windenergie,
        Biomasse,
        Photovoltaik,
        Wasserkraft,
        Geothermie 
    },
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
%   nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
    \addplot[black,fill=black!50!white] coordinates {
        (Windenergie,126.0) (Biomasse,50.4) (Photovoltaik,47.5) (Wasserkraft,20.2) (Geothermie,0.2)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `fixed` to the `nodes near coords style`:

```
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[
    conference,
    ]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\twh{\tera\watt\hour}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={Stromerzeugung in \SI{}{\twh}},
    symbolic x coords={
        Windenergie,
        Biomasse,
        Photovoltaik,
        Wasserkraft,
        Geothermie 
    },
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1},% <- changed
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
    \addplot[black,fill=black!50!white] coordinates {
        (Windenergie,126.0) (Biomasse,50.4) (Photovoltaik,47.5) (Wasserkraft,20.2) (Geothermie,0.2)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```